# Do I need to @Throws for every method during exception bubbling up in Kotlin?

Tags: java, kotlin, exception

```
fun fun1(id: String)
{
    addThings(3,4)
}

fun addThings(num1: Int, num2: Int)
{
    addNumbers(num1, num2)
}

@Throws(Exception::class)
fun addNumbers(num1: Int, num2: Int)
{
   throws Exception("error")
}
```

1. `Excption` from `addNumbers` will bubble up all the way to `fun1` is that right?
2. Is `@Throws` required for `addThings` and `fun1`?

Couldn't find any docs online...

Answer (score 3):

No.

You can find good documentation on this [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/exceptions.html).

In summary, Kotlin does not have checked exceptions. That means there is no "bubble up". There is no requirement for any of your functions to declare that they throw an exception or to use try-catch. Declaring the annotation @Throws is only strictly necessary for [Java interop](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/java-to-kotlin-interop.html#checked-exceptions), you may need it if you call that Kotlin function from a Java file.

You can read about why from Kotlin's project lead [Roman Elizarov](https://elizarov.medium.com/kotlin-and-exceptions-8062f589d07).

Comment: It’s not necessary for Java interop. It’s optional. Declaring it causes it to enforce it as a checked exception.